# How can I reuse my function without any error?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I want to make my lineEdits turn red if they are empty when I click submit button. After adding something back I want to make my lineEdit turn back to white. [image: This is what I have right now]

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QFileDialog
import sys, os
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from BlurWindow.blurWindow import blur

def input_validate(self,lineedit):
    if self.lineedit.text() == '':
      self.lineedit.setStyleSheet('''
      QLineEdit{font: 15pt "Yu Gothic"; border-style:none; border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,0,0,0.6); color:white; 
      }
      QLineEdit:focus {
      background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
      } ''')
      return False
    else:
      self.lineedit.setStyleSheet('''
      QLineEdit{font: 15pt "Yu Gothic"; border-style:none; border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.6); color:white; 
      }
      QLineEdit:focus {
      background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
      } ''')
      return True

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
    loadUi(r'D:\Workspace\Qt Designer\blur bg\blurtest.ui',self)
    self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
    blur(self.winId())
    self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)")

    self.browse1.clicked.connect(self.browsefile1)
    self.browse2.clicked.connect(self.browsefile2)
    self.submit.clicked.connect(self.submit1)
    self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
    blur(self.winId())
    self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)")

  def browsefile1(self):
    fname=QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,'Open File',os.getcwd())
    self.lineEdit1.setText(fname[0])
  def browsefile2(self):
    fname=QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,'Open File',os.getcwd())
    self.lineEdit2.setText(fname[0])
  def submit1(self):
    if not input_validate(self.lineEdit1) or not input_validate(self.lineEdit2):
      return
    print("successs")

app=QApplication(sys.argv)
mw=MainWindow()
mw.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

First I tried seperating this input_validate as a class :

```
class input_validate(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    if self.lineEdit.text() == '':
      self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet('''
      QLineEdit{font: 15pt "Yu Gothic"; border-style:none; border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,0,0,0.6); color:white; 
      }
      QLineEdit:focus {
      background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
      } ''')
      return False
    else:
      self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet('''
      QLineEdit{font: 15pt "Yu Gothic"; border-style:none; border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.6); color:white; 
      }
      QLineEdit:focus {
      background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
      } ''')
      return True
```

The error I got was
if not input_validate(self.lineEdit1) or not input_validate(self.lineEdit2):
TypeError: input_validate.**init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

So then I tried putting it inside the MainWindow class itself but this time it says
if not input_validate(self.lineEdit1) or not input_validate(self.lineEdit2):
NameError: name 'input_validate' is not defined

So I put it outside the MainWindow class to make it global and the first code block is what I have.

Now my error is
if not input_validate(self.lineEdit1) or not input_validate(self.lineEdit2):
TypeError: input_validate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'lineedit'

I don't know how can I solve this now. The long way would be to define the input_validate with linedit1 and lineedit2 separately but I want to figure out how can I reuse that code.

Also I wanted to know if it is ok to inherit QMainWindow instead of QWidget. This is supposed to be a one window thing for now with this as the first window to appear, so I selected it as a main window. Max it will have is a success popup or error popup message on clicking submit (which I guess I have to implement using QMessageBox)

Comment: Your `input_validate` is a class. Using it in an `if` condition makes absolutely no sense, and especially since that class has no such attribute. Use a standard function, and pass the widget as argument. Also, please take your time to study more about classes and instances, as it seems clear that you don't really understand what you're doing there, and randomly trying things like this isn't very effective.

Comment: hi again @musicamante yes i figured that's not how to use it in the class, so i shifted it outside as a function but now getting the error saying no argument is passed to that function so im confused what to do now

Comment: As already said, you should really take your time to seriously study what are classes and instances, but also the difference between functions and methods, or even the meaning of `self` in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Regarding the issue in comments:

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    ... #Other stuff

    #Here, if 'submit' is clicked, it will check both lineEdit1 and lineEdit2
    #self.input_validate(self.lineEdit1, self.lineEdit2)
    #EG: self.input_validate(self.a, self.b, ...)
    #No need to pass as list, just add commas with brackets
    self.submit.clicked.connect(lambda: self.input_validate(self.lineEdit1, self.lineEdit2)) #Triggers the function created below

    #If text is changed, no argument is passed so it defaults to check
    #only lineEdit1
    #If you do want to change both
    #self.lineEdit1.textChanged.connect(lambda: self.input_validate(self.lineEdit1, self.lineEdit2))
    self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.input_validate) 
    #It triggers whenever the text is changed in the lineEdit even with using setText,
    #If you want to just check when the user changes it, you can use textEdited. 

    def input_validate(self, *args):

        #If args is empty (no argument is passed), it defaults to self.lineEdit1
        if not args: args = [self.lineEdit1]

        for x in args:
            if x.text() == '':
                ... #Set StyleSheet for Red
            else:
                ... #Set StyleSheet for White
```

You can add any number of `lineEdit` to change using the function. Just separate it with a comma.
`self.input_validate(self.lineEdit1, self.lineEdit2, self.lineEdit3, ...)`.

**Original answer**:
Your approach is way off and can be a little complex than it may seem. You can simply define a function in `MainWindow` class for more simplicity and easier execution. In your first snippet of code, you have defined `input_validate` outside of the class.

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    ... #Other stuff

    self.submit.clicked.connect(self.input_validate) #Triggers the function created below
    
    self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.input_validate) 
    #It triggers whenever the text is changed in the lineEdit even with using setText,
    #If you want to just check when the user changes it, you can use textEdited. 

    def input_validate(self):
        if self.lineEdit.text() == '':
            ... #Set StyleSheet for Red
        else:
            ... #Set StyleSheet for White
```

Also, the `lineEdit` will turn to color Red if the user clears it. If you don't want it to happen you can add an argument in `input_validate`, and return the function if the argument is `True` so the function will not check for `lineEdit.text()`.

And if you have to add parameters in `connect`, you have to use `lambda`, e.g.: `self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(lambda: input_validate())`.

Comment: thanks, i did not know about .textChanged property :D will play around with this now
also i had placed my input_validate outside because i was getting an error saying input_validate not defined
and I had called input_validate as a seperate function because there is still functionality that i want to add after fetching the files by clicking submit button

Comment: For the error, `input_validate not defined`, just check if the function is actually inside the `class`, and it has it's first argument as `self` and you reference it as `self.input_validate()`.

Comment: it was inside the class but with lineedit as a parameter. putting self did make it work but then i cannot apply it using my logic since i dont think i can pass lineEdit1 or lineEdit2 to that function for checking. also using your logic, clicking submit button will make input_validate check all the lineEdits in my mainwindow? i think it only checks the first one so i think i have to seperately check it for each lineedit in the beginning

Comment: The code I provided only checks for `self.lineEdit`. If you want to pass other instances, you add an argument to the function like: `def input_validate(self, line=self.lineEdit):`, and while connecting the events for example for submit, you can do: `self.submit.clicked.connect(lambda: self.input_validate(self.lineEdit2))`. Also in the function, change the line `if self.lineEdit.text() == '':` to `if line.text() == '':`.

Comment: Also, if you want for both `lineEdit1` and `lineEdit2`, you can change argument to `def input_validate(self, line=[self.lineEdit)]:`, and adding a `for` loop in the function. `for x in line:`, next line, `if x.text() == '':` and so on. And for executing the function, `self.submit.clicked.connect(lambda: self.input_validate([self.lineEdit1, self.lineEdit2]))`

Comment: hi sam i tried what you said. first issue i got is self not defined in line=[self.lineEdit] so i set line = None in argument instead and then if line is None: line=[self.lineEdit]. Then I got the issue for x in line: bool object is not iterable so i decided to call it from function submit1 instead of connecting it to submit button. now it turns red if i leave lineedits empty but if i add something to the lineedit now i get error saying if x.text() == '':
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: I edited my answer, I hope it resolves your issue. If not then I'll add you in discord.